# How to create a 216 RGB colors using Processing

Tags: processing

How to generate a 6x36 palette of RGB Color rectangles?
I don't know where or how to start. It should look like this:

[image: 216 RGB COLOR PALETTE]

This particular example has 50 by 40 pixel-sized rectangles. Adding it all up results in a screen size of 1800 by 240 so our code will include:

```
    size(1800, 240); 
    background(100);
.
.
.
rect(x,y,50,40);
```

(obviously many lines of code were omitted)
As we have learned, RGB colors are in 8-bit, represented from 0-255 per channel. The resulting possible colors are over 16 Million. In our case, we will be representing each channel with only 6 colors each, from 0-5.
Instead of trying to pinpoint the 6 values out of the standard 255, we can make our lives simpler by creating a custom color range by adding this to our code:

```
colorMode(RGB, 5);
```

The resulting values of RGB are the following

[image: VALUES OF RGB]

Although our grid specifically transposes the rows and columns in order to display in on our screen better.

It goes without saying that this table will be generated using loops. The tricky part of this exercise is figuring out how to generate the numbers into rows and columns since RGB has three values. If we would pay attention to the values generated, the rows of our table is determined by the value of R, and the columns are values of G and B. We would then need to create loops that would increment the R, G, and B values this way.

Adding text to your rectangles is not required, but I found it helpful that I can see how the loop is going. You can easily display text by adding this line of code:

```
text(r+""+g+""+b,x,y);
```

The 216 colors we would end up displaying are actually the Web Safe Colors. Old browsers used to have trouble rendering all 16 Million RGB colors and they needed to trim the gamut down.